# Py4JJavaError in pyflink Table api

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

This code converts pandas to flink table do the transformation than again converting back to pandas. It perfectly works fine when I use `filter` `filter` than `select` but gives me an error when i add `group_by` and `order_by`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

f_s_env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
f_s_settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().use_old_planner().in_streaming_mode().build()
table_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(f_s_env, environment_settings=f_s_settings)

df = pd.read_csv("dataBase/New/candidate.csv")

col = ['candidate_id', 'candidate_source_id', 'candidate_first_name',
       'candidate_middle_name', 'candidate_last_name', 'candidate_email',
       'created_date', 'last_modified_date', 'last_modified_by']

table = table_env.from_pandas(df,col)
table.filter("candidate_id > 322445")\
    .filter("candidate_first_name === 'Libby'")\
    .group_by("candidate_id, candidate_source_id")\
    .select("candidate_id, candidate_source_id")\
    .order_by("candidate_id").to_pandas()
```

My error is

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3164.orderBy.
: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: A limit operation on unbounded tables is currently not supported.
    at org.apache.flink.table.operations.utils.SortOperationFactory.failIfStreaming(SortOperationFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.flink.table.operations.utils.SortOperationFactory.createSort(SortOperationFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.table.operations.utils.OperationTreeBuilder.sort(OperationTreeBuilder.java:409)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableImpl.orderBy(TableImpl.java:401)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the SQL is not valid, you cannot do groupBy without any aggs...(altaugh the exception is not mentioned it), if you try remove the groupBy (but keep the orderBy) is it working?

Comment: no it doesn't work if i keep orderBy and remove groupBy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the documentation, you will see that with the [Table API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/tableApi.html#orderby-offset--fetch), ORDER BY is only supported for batch queries. If you switch to [SQL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql/queries.html#orderby--limit), then you can have streaming queries that sort on an ascending time attribute.

Sorting by anything else in an unbounded streaming query is simply impossible, since sorting requires full knowledge of the input.